# hello Everyone, probleme with setInterval(Mytimer,5000) dosent execute the fuction Mytimer , the server online can be push but not the offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, health-check

in this code i wanna check the app if down or up so i use a serverlist how i created some server to test, and i can ping with pingserver(server.url) if response code equal 200 i push the information with the name +online if not i need to check the server for 2minutes with setInterval(Mytimer,120000) in the else condition but its not executed if anyone can help please and thank you all.

```
async function pingAllServers() {
   
   let serverListWithResponseCode = []
    for (let i = 0; i < serverList.length; i++) {
       let server = serverList[i]
       let responseCode = await pingServer(server.url)
       if (responseCode == 200) {
           serverListWithResponseCode.push({
               name: server.alias,
               responseCode: responseCode,
               url: server.url,
               port: server.port,
               base: server.base
           })
       }
       else {
          setInterval(Mytimer, 120000)
       
     async function Mytimer()  {
           return(
                            serverListWithResponseCode.push({
                            name: server.alias,
                            responseCode: responseCode,
                            url: server.url,
                            port: server.port,
                            base: server.base
                                                           })
                 )                                          
                          }
           }
   }
   return serverListWithResponseCode

   }
```

Comment: you understand that every time you run `setInterval(Mytimer, 120000)` you start a new interval - did you mean `setTimeout` - also 120000 in teh code ... 5000 in the title - and finally ... `MyTimer` doesn't need to be `async` since you never `await`, and there's no point in `return` since the returned value goes nowhere does nothing - and lastly, defining a function inside a loop is definitely a no-no

Comment: the function mytimer without return, i forget it

Comment: @JaromandaX tank you for your advice , my function need to be async cause in app.get i have let response = await pingAllServers()

Comment: yeah, that's the least of your problems

Comment: Mytimer does NOT need to be `async` .... as it does nothing asynchronous

Comment: and `async` won't help your `return serverListWithResponseCode` not having the results of those calls to Mytimer

Comment: thing is, the code in the else condition IS executed, every 2 minutes ... but all it does is push the information it had at the start to the array ... after you've returned the array

Comment: thank you boss,it's really helpful for me